# nslookup not retrieving authoritative answer

Tags: domain-name-system, nslookup

I'm trying to get an authoritative answer using nslookup but it's not working

```
$nslookup animeflv.net matt.ns.cloudflare.com

Server:  matt.ns.cloudflare.com
Address:  108.162.193.131#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    animeflv.net
Address:  172.67.70.233
Name:    animeflv.net
Address:  104.26.0.100
Name:    animeflv.net
Address:  104.26.1.100
```

Why? Is it cache, the router? How can I query matt.ns.cloudflare.com?

Comment: I get an authoritative answer running the same query from my machine. Do you have anything that might be intercepting external DNS queries?

Comment: Do you get same behavior if you query `2606:4700:58::adf5:3b83#53` (which is `matt.ns.cloudflare.com` IPv6 address)? The answer is correct, but something may alter the DNS packets. `dig @matt.ns.cloudflare.com animeflv.net | grep flags` shows `;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 3, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.